# super() infinite looping

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm having some inheritance problems with Ruby.

```
class A < Hash
    def initialize()
        super()
        createB
    end
    def createB
        @b=B.new
    end
end
class B < A
    def initialize()
        super()
        createB
    end
    def createB
        @b={x,y,z}
    end
end
```

the above code creates an infinite loop where an instance of `A` tries to create an instance of `B` which then calls `super()` which will create another instance of `B` and so on. How can I call `super()` from `B` but not call `createB` from `A`'s `initialize` method. I have thought about adding an option for `A`'s initialization method along the lines of `is_b=false` and only running `createB` when `is_b==false`, but it's pretty ugly to do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it at all, really? This code does not parse correctly.

As far as I remember, there would be no such problem, because the `createB` from class B would fully override `createB` from class A, so there will be no "loop" simply because the creation of "B"-type object will **not** trigger the A.createB method.

Proof, Ruby 1.9.3:

```
C:\Users\quetzalcoatl>pry
[1] pry(main)> class A < Hash
[1] pry(main)*   def initialize()
[1] pry(main)*     puts "A.init"
[1] pry(main)*     super()
[1] pry(main)*     createB
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)*   def createB
[1] pry(main)*     puts "A.createB"
[1] pry(main)*     @b=B.new
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> class B < A
[2] pry(main)*   def initialize()
[2] pry(main)*     puts "B.init"
[2] pry(main)*     super()
[2] pry(main)*     createB
[2] pry(main)*   end
[2] pry(main)*   def createB
[2] pry(main)*     puts "B.createB"
[2] pry(main)*     @b={:x=>:x,:y=>:y,:z=>:z} # fixed it for you :)
[2] pry(main)*   end
[2] pry(main)* end
=> nil

[3] pry(main)> A.new     /// manually creating A object to see what happens
A.init                   /// <- ...obvious
A.createB                /// <- A.init called createB (from the very same A object)
B.init                   /// <- A.createB just have created NEW object B
A.init                   /// <- that new B.init called its super()==A.init
B.createB                *** <- A.init (base of the new B) called createB (->derived)!
B.createB                /// <- that new B.init called its createB (->derived)
=> {}

[4] pry(main)> B.new
B.init
A.init                   /// <- save as above
B.createB                /// <- save as above
B.createB                /// <- save as above
=> {}
[5] pry(main)>
```

As you see, when creating the "B"-type object, the original method from "A" class was never called (place marked as ***)

Comment: This answer helps, thanks. I didn't actually try the code, the code posted is a stripped-down version of my actual code. I assumed that B.init's super calling A.init would then call A.createB. The fact that it doesn't is convenient for my current uses, but what if I wanted B.init to call A.init and A.createB? How could I manage that?

Comment: @aaachilless: It would not call A#createB. The object executing A's initializer is an instance of B, so `self.createB` will resolve to B's implementation of the method, not A's. Intentionally calling a superclass's implementation of a method outside of an override of the same method is inconvenient (you need to get the method from the class and bind it before you can call it), which is good because it is usually a mistake to do so.

Comment: I see. It's pretty intuitive when you put it that way, thanks.